# Angular - Form Validator is unable to show the error message

Tags: angular, typescript, validation, angular-reactive-forms

I set up form validation.
I want the message "Minimum characters 4" to appear if the number of characters is less than four or if the number of characters is more than eight then the message "Maximum characters 8" appears.

**app.component.ts**

```js
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  form = this.fb.group({
    password: ['', {
      validators: [
        Validators.minLength(4),
        Validators.maxLength(8)
      ]
    }]

  });

  get password() {
    return this.form.controls['password'];
  }

}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="form">

  <input type="password" placeholder="Password" formControlName="password">

  <div *ngIf="password.errors?.['minLength']"> Minimum characters </div>

  <div *ngIf="password.errors?.['maxLength']"> Maximum characters </div>

  <button> Login </button>

</form>
```

Why does not it work? I made it from the Angular documentation. https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#validating-input-in-reactive-forms

https://github.com/MyTestPerson/form-validator/tree/master/src/app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Validators.minLength()`](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators#minlength) return the error with `minlength` property

> Returns
>
> ValidatorFn: A validator function that returns an error map with the minlength property if the validation check fails, otherwise null.

```
password.errors?.['minlength']
```

and

[`Validators.maxLength()`](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators#maxlength) return the error with `maxlength` property.

> Returns
>
> ValidatorFn: A validator function that returns an error map with the maxlength property if the validation check fails, otherwise null.

```
password.errors?.['maxlength']
```

[Sample StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pzp9pv?file=src/app/app.component.html)

---

FYI, the validators for the form control can be simplified with:

```js
password: ['',
  [
    Validators.minLength(4),
    Validators.maxLength(8)
  ]
]
```

Comment: The problem was that I was specifying camel style

Comment: <div *ngIf="password.errors?.['minLength']"> Minimum characters 4</div>

Answer (score 2):

Use the below command to preview why the problem is occouring.

```
{{ password.errors | json }}
```

My version.

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <input type="password" placeholder="Password" formControlName="password" />
  <!-- {{ password.errors | json }} -->
  <div *ngIf="password.errors && password.errors['minlength']">
    Minimum characters is
    {{
      password.errors &&
        password.errors['minlength'] &&
        password.errors['minlength'].requiredLength
    }}
  </div>

  <div *ngIf="password.errors && password.errors['maxlength']">
    Maximum characters
    {{
      password.errors &&
        password.errors['maxlength'] &&
        password.errors['maxlength'].requiredLength
    }}
  </div>

  <button>Login</button>
</form>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-12-dze3nv)

Comment: The problem was that I was specifying camel style

Comment: <div *ngIf="password.errors?.['minLength']"> Minimum characters 4</div>